# How to get a formatted string in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

In OCaml, I can use `Printf.printf` to output formatted string, like

```
Printf.printf "Hello %s %d\n" world 123
```

However, `printf` is a kind of output.

---

What I wish for is not for output, but for a string. For example, I want

```
let s = something "Hello %s %d\n" "world" 123
```

then I can get `s = "Hello World 123"`

---

How can I do that?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use Printf.sprintf:

```
# Printf.sprintf "Hello %s %d\n" "world" 123;;
- : string = "Hello world 123\n"
```

Comment: can I define like this: `let fmt = "Hello %s %d\n";; Printf.sprintf fmt "world" 123`?

Comment: @JacksonTale, I'm not really sure. It seems you can do `let fmt = Printf.sprintf "Hello %s %d\n";; fmt "world" 123;;` however.

Comment: @JacksonTale: if you do it that way, it will infer the wrong type (string instead of format thingy). In OCaml there is an "overload" for string literals between strings and format thingies. To make it infer the right thing, you must use `format_of_string` (which is an identify function, but helps the type system): `let fmt = format_of_string "Hello %s %d\n";; Printf.sprintf fmt "world" 123`. Or maybe you can just do `(fun fmt -> Printf.sprintf fmt "world" 123) "Hello %s %d\n"` if that is sufficient.

Answer (score 9):

You can do this:

```
$ ocaml
        OCaml version 4.00.1

# let fmt = format_of_string "Hello %s %d";;
val fmt : (string -> int -> '_a, '_b, '_c, '_d, '_d, '_a) format6 = <abstr>
# Printf.sprintf fmt "world" 123;;
- : string = "Hello world 123"
```

The `format_of_string` function (as the name implies) transforms a string literal into a format. Note that formats must ultimately be built from string literals, because there is compiler magic involved. You can't read in a string and use it as a format, for example. (It wouldn't be typesafe.)